# No deleted resources in local history?

Tags: java, eclipse

I lost my project code by mistake. I dont know what happened. All my packages are empty. When I try to restore eclipse, it is showing this message:

> **No deleted resources in local history for selected container**.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: If the files are deleted from the disk than I believe you cant restore. Check this https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=201013/

Comment: In that link showing that it is not possible.It's Okay But is it possible to get the code from ear files and war files?\